# Super visa for parents

Tags: usa, canada

I have my parents in Canada with me currently. We applied for their super visa when they were in India; now they have approved super visa and asked for passport to be submitted outside Canada.

Can I just send my parents passport to US Vac in New York to get it stamped, as they are currently with us in Canada?

Comment: Who (or what office) "asked for passport to be submitted outside Canada?" What is "US Vac" ?

Comment: What did the notification from IRCC say about instructions for VACs where the passport can be submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, usually it is not problem to get your passport stamped at a U.S. VAC, if you are willing to assume the risk of transborder courier services (not that it is necessarily higher than sending your passport across Canada).

You may need to arrange the courier services to return the passport back to Canada, and your money order or bank draft for the fee payment needs to be in USD.

Getting a super visa counterfoil  does not mean a person in Canada automatically has their current stay in Canada extended. They must leave Canada and then be admitted on a super visa counterfoil to stay for up to five years in Canada.